# how to send a message to a specific channel using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do this.
I have a module that when it is executed it is supposed to send a message to a specific channel, but it does not.

I have tried:

```
client.channels.cache.get('771081627768979516').send('test')
```

as well as

```
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(c => c.name === '#logs')
channel.send('test')
```

(using both `logs` and `#logs`)

I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: The name does not include the `#`. Also, please post any errors that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function was not getting called right -_-